# QPushButton Stylesheet Causes Artefact On Press

Tags: qt, user-interface, widget, stylesheet, qt-designer

I'm having a problem with my stylesheet on a QPushButton:

```
QPushButton#convertButton
{
    color: #00FF00;
}
```

Pretty simple as you can see and the text colour gets set correctly. The problem arises when i click the button, a strange artefact appears like an inner part of the button has been selected. Unfortunately i don't have enough rep to post an image.

If i remove the stylesheet the artefact does not appear on press.

Any help welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
QPushButton:focus
{
    outline: none;
}
```

This removes the artefact, but unfortunately the 'shading' style of a focused widget is now also lost. If someone knows how to retain this please let me know (i couldn't find the default stylesheet online).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to edit the substate "pressed" of your button thanks to :

```
QPushButton:pressed
{
    color: #00FF00;
}
```

I tried you example on my computer but I can't see the artefact you speek about. But maybe it is because I have not the same default style than you.

Comment: This only changes the colour of the text on press (as expected) and still leaves the original problem.